# Adding Background Image Using CSS

Tags: html, css, django, web

In my django project I try to add background image to html template.  But it does not work my code is like this

```
background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");
```

error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/bg.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help me to fix this

[I try it different ways...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhMqu.png)
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgzQl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
background-image: url("./img/bg.jpg");
```

Also can you post an image showing structure of your project?

Comment: I added folder structure

Answer (score 0):

replace your bakground- image with this code

```
background-image: url("{% static "/img/bg.jpg" %}");
```

after that add this in your setting file

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\','/'), ] follow this answer in stackoverflow [stackoverflow link][1] hope it works.
```

Comment: and if you want I can conduct a Zoom meetin for you